# Shiny icon keeps running after report is loaded

Tags: r, shiny

I loaded the sample report (new file > Rmarkdown) in Shiny Server in Rmd format and it is working ok. But when shared html report to user, the "loading" icon keeps running forever.
[image]

Comment: Sample code would be good

Comment: sample report, as said in description.